# Heroku: composer.json in sub folder

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

Lets take the following folder structure:

```
www/
www/composer.json
www/index.php
www/vendor
www/backend/
www/backend/composer.json
www/backend/index.php
www/backend/vendor
```

As you can see I have 2 projects, 1 project being a subfolder in the main folder. The main folder gets deployed with heroku and heroku installs the packages from composer.json automatically. Is there a way to instruct heroku or composer.json to also install the www/backend/composer.json packages inside the www/backend/vendor folder?

Or can I specify some of the packages inside the www/compposer.json (not all) to install under the www/backend/vendor folder? Also to generate 2 autoloads file in both www/vendor/ and www/backend/vendor/ ?

Comment: Try something like this in your root  composer.json file: `"scripts": {
        "composer install": "backend"}`

Comment: So this will run composer install inside the backend folder? I cannot test this righ now since the deployment is not ready.

Comment: Yes It will install the composer.json in backend , I'm not sure but you have to test this command.

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? I'm looking to also deploy to Heroku with my php app and composer.json in an /api subfolder. This question would be of more use to people if it had a conclusion :o)

Comment: Yes, i was able to do this adding the following in the main composer.json: "scripts" : {
    "post-install-cmd" : "cd api;composer  install;composer  update"
  }

Comment: @keepwalking This worked for me too. You should add this as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afterall, i was able to do this adding the following in the main composer.json:

> "scripts" : { "post-install-cmd" : "cd api;composer install;composer
>   update" }

Answer (score 2):

For people looking for this in the future:
As indicated [by the answer from keepwalking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322923/6903994) you can use the "scripts" key in the "composer.json", as described in the ["Scripts" section of the Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md). Interestingly, you can also use arrays for individual events.

You can use bash commands, such as `cd` and `mv` but you can also use `&&` to chain commands.
So, my example would be:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "cd www && composer install",
      "cd www/backend && composer install"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

This has the following flow:

1. You run `composer install` in the project root
2. Composer finishes installing the dependencies and emits the "post-install-cmd" event
3. Composer runs the first command in the "post-install-cmd" array
4. Composer finishes the first command in the "post-install-cmd" array
5. Composer runs the second command in the "post-install-cmd" array